# how to display the comments under the post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have problem in my project i'm new in MVC so plz help me out. I have problem to display the comments under the relevant the Post like we have post in face book and we comment just under the post and it display, I Have displayed and listed all the posts and under this i have displayed the comments field, i just want to know how the relevant comment can be displayed,
**View**

```
    @foreach (Post item in Model.posts)
{
    foreach(Comment c in item.comments)
    {
<div>

    <p>
        @item.Body
    </p>
    <p>@item.timeDate</p>
    <p>@c.Body</p>

</div>   
    using (Html.BeginForm("CreateComment", "Posts", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Comment</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comment.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.comment.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.comment.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comment.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.comment.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.comment.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comment.Body)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.comment.Body)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.comment.Body)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comment.dateTime)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.comment.dateTime, new { id = "datepicker", @Value = @DateTime.Now })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.post.timeDate)
        </div>       
        <div class="editor-field">
           <input type ="text" hidden="hidden" value="@item.Id" name="txtpostId"/>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.comment.PostId)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    }
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        objVmPost.comment = new Comment();
        objVmPost.post = new Post();
        List<Post> mylist = db.Posts.Include(post => post.Comments).ToList();
        objVmPost.posts = mylist;
        return View("Index",objVmPost);
    }
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(VmPost objVmpost)
    {
        objVmpost.comment.PostId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["txtpostId"]);
        db.Comments.Add(objVmpost.comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        List<Post> mylist = objPostDb.GetAll().ToList();
        objVmpost.posts = mylist;
        return View("index", objVmpost);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public partial class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}

public partial class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
            this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime timeDate { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

[This is the problem click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnMsO.png)

Comment: `foreach (Comment c in Model.comments)` displays all comments, not the comments associated with a `Post` You need `foreach (Comment c in item.Comments)` (and your view model does not need a property for `comments` - the `Post` model already contains a property for its collecton of `Comment`

Comment: I have did this but it only display those posts which have comments and displays not proper, it display like::  if the post have 2 comments, it display the post two times with each comment

Comment: It does not! (but you have not shown what you tried so we cannot possible guess the mistake you have made)

Comment: look at the script of view i have put the script in foreach loop i have changed the nested foreach as you said

Comment: and what you want me to show

Comment: The code you have now tried which you claim is not working. But Paweł Hemperek has already explained how you need to do it - and based on your comments to that correct answer, its clear you do not understand - if you followed it correctly you could not possibly get what you are claiming unless the data in your database is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you're doing this

```
List<Comment> cmntlist = db.Comments.ToList();
```

which translates into SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `comments`
```

so, you are not retreiving related comments, but all comments stored in database.

You could use lazy loading mechanism and your controller would look like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    objVmPost.post = new Post();
    List<Post> mylist = db.Posts.ToList();
    objVmPost.posts = mylist;
    return View("Index",objVmPost);
}
```

or eager loading

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    objVmPost.post = new Post();
    List<Post> mylist = db.Posts.Include(post => post.Comments).ToList();
    objVmPost.posts = mylist;
    return View("Index",objVmPost);
}
```

You can read more about [lazy loading and eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

No matter which approach you would like to take, your foreach loops should look like this:

```
foreach(var post in Model.Posts){
    <p>@post.Body</p>
    <p>@post.timeDate</p>
    foreach(var comment in post.Comments){
        <p>@comment.Body</p>
    }
    // here you can add your comment form
}
```

Comment: I have did the same but the problem is it displays only the commented post s and the other problem is it display the post as many times as comment, like one post have two comments so the post display twice with each comment,

Comment: @FaisalShahab Also what do you mean by _it displays only the commented post_?

Comment: Hemperek Commented post means those post on which people comment.

Comment: I don't wanna show only those posts which are commented by people i want to show all the post and also  those posts which are commented by people just like face book, in facebook you can see multiple user comment on single post and it display the list of comments under the post

Comment: my view is already strongly typed with VMPost In VMPost there are 4 properties public Post post {set; get;}   public List<Post> post {set; get;}   public Comment comment {set; get;}   public List<Comment> comments {set; get;}

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand your problem. On Facebook they show a post and related comments below it. `db.Posts.Include(post => post.Comments).ToList();` will retrieve all posts with associated comments, so you can display everything the way you want. You mentioned that if post has two comments, you would like to display this post two times - it's not the way they are doing this at Facebook. Please clarify your question (maybe some graphical example?)

Comment: i don't want display two time the post this is the problem it displayed 2 time i want to fix this

Comment: I think the problem is in view foreach loop where i out the code kindly review it in detail

Comment: @FaisalShahab I updated my answer again - look and tell me if this solves your problem.

Comment: With this code the comment form display only under the comment not under the posts the comment form should display under the post

Comment: @FaisalShahab look now. Also - please try to think not only ask questions. I made really small change you could easily figure out by yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot  it worked just put the form in first  foreach loop and it worked not i can hide them with the jquery thanks